# How to update user profile through Mixins in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mixins, put, updatemodel

Need to edit `user profile` using `mixins`, by sending a `PUT` request to corresponding url *(that contains the id of the user whose info is to be updated )*

What is missing/needs to be changed in the following code to achieve the above?

**models.py**:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'date_joined',)

        def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
            user = super(UserSerializer, self).restore_object(attrs, instance)
            user.set_password(attrs['password'])
            return user

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id','user','profile_picture',)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserMixin(object,):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

class UserProfileView(UserMixin, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    pass
```

Do ask if more clarity is required.

Comment: But what is your problem? Maybe explain what you're getting with code mentioned above and what is missing to achieve required task?

Comment: First of all , my user profile is not getting updated (failing without any error)...... secondly my doubt is  if i update the user profile will it get automatically updated in user model also ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use [ModelViewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) for updating the user-profile

```
class UserProfileViewViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
        serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
        permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

        def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            user_profile = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(user_profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_update(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```